# Stop zoom in for the webview in android for titanium

Tags: android, titanium

I have loaded local html page on webview.

i run for IOS there is not zoom effect.

When i run on android its shows zoom in and zoom out for me.

how to stop zoom effect for android.

```
"#aboutWebView":{

    url : 'aboutUs.html',
    backgroundColor:'transparent',
    touchEnabled:true,
    willHandleTouches:false,
    enableZoomControls:false
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try adding this to your html file in the head tag

```
<meta name = "viewport" content = "user-scalable = no">
```

If this doesnt work try this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=0">
```

Comment: I wish I could give you more than one +1. Thanks a lot!